# Why am I not seeing Code-Author Checkbox in my Inlay Hint configuration?

Tags: pycharm, inlay-hints

## Version of PyCharm

```
PyCharm 2020.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-203.7717.81, built on March 25, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+8-b1145.96 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1957M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: Batch Scripts Support, CMD Support,     com.andrey4623.rainbowcsv, com.carbonblack.intellij.rpmspec, com.chesterccw.excelreader, com.maxifom.pyenv-integration, net.seesharpsoft.intellij.plugins.csv, zielu.gittoolbox, Docker,     gherkin, net.ashald.envfile
```

My project is integrated with a Gitlab repo in PyCharm.  I.e., can see git history, branches, and such.

## Expected

I want to see the author's name like this:
[image]

The Inlay Hints show Code Author:
[image]

## Actual

When I try to configure PyCharm's inlay hints, I don't see the author code:
[image]

## Reference:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/investigate-changes.html#show-author-of-changes